# outputting key value pairs that aren't null in Key Value pairs in arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, key-value

So inside the folders array. I want to print out the 'name' of the folders that don't have null as their size.

```js
let folders = [
  {
    name:'user_name',
    size: 5455,
    information: ' '
    },
  {
    name:'untitled',
    size: 545343,
    information: 'no description'
  },
  {
    name:'new_user',
    size: null
  }
];
```

So i've made this code in order to get the names of the folders that don't have null as their size but when I test it, it only prints out all the arrays. I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```js
folders.forEach((item) => {
  let info = folders.filter((f) => {
    if (f.size !== null);
    return item.name
  })
  console.log(info)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, consider using `Array#filter()` in combination with `Array#map()`.

First, use `filter()` to isolate the folder items where the size is not `null`:

```
.filter(folder => folder.size !== null)
```

and then use `map()` to transform each folder item in the filtered result, to the name of that folder:

```
.map(folder => folder.name)
```

The complete example can be seen as:

```js
let folders = [
  {
    name:'user_name',
    size: 5455,
    information: ' '
    },
  {
    name:'untitled',
    size: 545343,
    information: 'no description'
  },
  {
    name:'new_user',
    size: null
  }
];

let result = folders
.filter(folder => folder.size !== null)
.map(folder => folder.name)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This only filters out the null sizes though, OP was looking for the *names* of said folders

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for pointing that out! Completely missed that detail - have just updated answer, much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `if (f.size !== null);` should not have a trailing semicolon - that will make the test meaningless, because no matter whether it's null or not, the semicolon will mean that the line that follows will be executed regardless. Another is that `filter` *always* returns the original item in the array, if the test passes - for what you're doing, you might use `filter` (to filter out null sizes) followed by `map` (to get to the `name`s):

```js
let folders = [
  {
    name:'user_name',
    size: 5455,
    information: ' '
    },
  {
    name:'untitled',
    size: 545343,
    information: 'no description'
  },
  {
    name:'new_user',
    size: null
  }
];
console.log(
  folders
    .filter(({ size }) => size !== null)
    .map(({ name }) => name)
);
```

If you wanted to achieve it in a *single* iteration over the array, use `reduce` to `filter` and `map` at the same time:

```js
let folders = [
  {
    name:'user_name',
    size: 5455,
    information: ' '
    },
  {
    name:'untitled',
    size: 545343,
    information: 'no description'
  },
  {
    name:'new_user',
    size: null
  }
];
console.log(
  folders.reduce((a, { name, size }) => {
    if (size !== null) a.push(name);
    return a;
  }, [])
);
```

Comment: Just assign the result to a variable, and then `console.log` that variable. eg `const result = folders.reduce(...`